# extract a logs before one hour from log file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to grep logs before 1  hour

like this:-

```
grep "$(date --date='1 hour ago +%H') /var/log/oss.log | grep "MTS" > oss.new.log
```

But its searching for `"04"` in log  and my output like this

```
frwY01jtaX 00:04:46,739 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS 
OlvYM6czmz 00:04:54,348 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS 
5iUr2l1LNv 01:04:40,764 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
EZ35Xum6eG 02:04:10,328 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
pCxbg584le 02:04:21,236 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
K3rPlPgIpb 03:04:50,529 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
rRz4IW94mB 03:04:55,728 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
Ir91iBSCUc 04:00:05,571 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
jp00Sfavl5 04:00:15,489 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
Ks5w1eP90F 04:00:40,794 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
```

Its matches `04` in every hour.

I only need below output

```
Ir91iBSCUc 04:00:05,571 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
jp00Sfavl5 04:00:15,489 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
Ks5w1eP90F 04:00:40,794 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
jkljkfhknk 04:00:41,768 ERROR SiteDetectionUtil:47 MTS
```

only `04` hour logs

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
grep " $(date --date='1 hour ago' '+%H').*MTS" /var/log/oss.log > oss.new.log
```

Or

```
grep "\s$(date --date='1 hour ago' '+%H').*MTS" /var/log/oss.log > oss.new.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before and a ":" after to your grep part .
eg grep `04:` should be the output of your date command